# Bad content width on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, width

I have website in wordpress and I have a small problem with content. On computers main content shows fine. As you can see on mobile device, content has approx. 50% of width and I don't know why.. Can anybody help me please?

Website:
http://www.djreneek.com

Mobile screenshot: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19898988/Screenshot_2013-07-31-21-41-18.png

Thank you very much

EDIT: now I see diacritics doesn't work on mobile devices too... (ščťžýá etc..)

Comment: the horizontal line underneath your content indicates that you have a container who's width is much bigger than the actual content. The webpage on mobile fits the screen, so it will show the entire container.

Comment: Hm... can you tell me how to fix that please?

Comment: Yea but I need you to answer this first. It's wordpress, so are you using one of their templates or did you write it yourself? If it's one of their templates, do you have at least a basic understanding of html and css? And do you have access to the code to change it? I've never worked with wordpress so idk if they let you change their templates

Comment: I wrote my template. Yes, I understand html/css. I have access to ftp of course.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have set a viewport within the `<head>` of your document catering for mobile browsers.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Thank you. I'm not at home now but I will try add this line tomorrow.

Comment: Tried, didn't help me

Comment: yes this won't work because you don't have media queries, so there's no purpose for it.

Comment: so how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your wrapper on the website. If you look at the screenshot, there is a horizontal line that extends past the actual content, which means your wrapper or container is too big. Try using `max-width: n px;` on your wrapper. If that doesn't work try media queries.

For example in your css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    #wrapper {width: n px;}

}
```

It says that if the width of the screen is >= 600px, update these styles.

This would go underneath your styling for the wrapper. If you do go this route, you'll want to implement what Vector answered with the additional meta tag. It basically tells the document that there are media queries.